# Matplotlib shows date in POSIX time

Tags: python, matplotlib

My [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ym8SX2wSFUtHI5bnZd89BCtdHr-IKyK3cqduhsEkdT4/edit#gid=0) contains order dates and gross sales. I have the problem that `xticks` shows POSIX time for X which is not readable for humans. Do you have any idea how to plot it in a readable way? I had to transform to POSIX in order to .fit my model.

[image]

```
from sklearn import linear_model

def load_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['created', 'total_gross'], parse_dates=['created'])
    # The following line could be replaced with parse_dates=['created'] above
    # df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    return df.set_index('created').resample('D').sum().fillna(0)

df = load_data()
df.info()

# Create and Fit a Linear Regression Model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# convert to POSIX time by dividing by 10**9
X = df.index.astype('int64').values.reshape(-1,1) // 10**9

regr.fit(X, y)
y_predict = regr.predict(X)
plt.plot(X, y_predict)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You may use the [pandas datetime builtin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Moreover using the [pandas.DataFrame.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) function may be easier.

Comment: Hi Manu, you mean instead of  `X = df.index.astype('int64').values.reshape(-1,1) // 10**9` I should rather try it with `to_datetime`? Or at which point would I use that function?

Comment: consider first using pandas plot functions. You may not need to convert dates to int64. On a less important part, try avoiding one-liner, it is harder to read (you may follow the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) as it is python, not C)

Comment: Okay I will try that, thank you for your advice!

Comment: What I just wondered that you mentioned I might not need to convert dates to int64. I do that for the `.fit` method at the first place. I don't see how this could work without transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use POSIX time and matplotlib you can use `numpy` and `datetime`

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

dateconv = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)
date = dateconv(X)
```

You can then change the plotting routine to:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(date, y_predict)
xfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Which retruns:

[image]

I would encourage you to use matplotlib for plotting time series over using pandas `df.plot()` because pandas timestamps and matplotlib get wonky when you are trying to control the formats of the dates.

Comment: The only var. that confuses me is the `dates.DateFormatter`. Where does `dates` come from?

Comment: Shoot. forgot to add that.  `import matplotlib.dates as dates`